# Java EXP4J: Correct precedence of factorials?

Tags: java, parsing

I'm using the documentation's stock factorial operator which looks like this:

```
factorial = new Operator("!", 1, true, Operator.PRECEDENCE_POWER + 1) {
        @Override public double apply(double... args) {
            final long arg = (long) args[0];
            if ((double) arg != args[0]) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operand for factorial has to be an " + "integer");
            }
            if (arg < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The operand of the factorial can not " +
                                                   "be " +
                                                   "less than zero");
            }
            double result = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= arg; i++) {
                result *= i;
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
```

It works as intended for regular expressions, but when I have an expression like
`5^(2)!`  it returns `25` when the expected answer would be`1.55e25`. It takes the `2` as its argument instead of the final answer of the power.

I tried messing around with the precedence but nothing seems to be making a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try with the backslash \?  With "\" you escape special characters

Comment: I don't understand how that's relevant. Can you explain?

Comment: What happens when you evaluate `(5^(2))!` ?

Comment: That sounds like the right precedence for a factorial to me. If you want the `!` to bind to the `5^(2)` instead of the `(2)`, you should have placed the parentheses like `(5^2)!`.

Comment: What result would you have expected for `5^2!`? Or for `5*2!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems correct to me.  5^2! should be 25 as should 5^(2)!

Google confirmed both of those.

Perhaps you meant (5^2)! instead?  That should fix it.

I don't know any case where putting parens around a single number changes the order of operation.